# WPF 2D in 3D view Animations : Performance issue

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, animation, rendering

I've put a `TextBlock` in a 3D panel ([Planerator](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/greg_schechter/2007/10/26/enter-the-planerator-dead-simple-3d-in-wpf-with-a-stupid-name/)) and I used a `Storyboard` to animate it. (as crawl text)

When the field of view is 1 everything works fine, But if I set the field of view to more than 50 the frame rate will drop sharply and rendering will be choppy.

I used the`CompositionTarget.rendering`.

Please see the following images:

[image]

[image]

I need to 2D animations in 3d view with good performance.

Please tell me how can I solve this problem? Should I leave WPF and go to the DirectX?

**UPDATE 1 :**

I just want to move **ONE** 2Dtext in 3D space , but the performance is poor.(rendering isn't smooth it is choppy)

This is [**a sample project**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7xJ3vpXXdvQT0wxc3VKNXkwTmc/view?usp=sharing).

**UPDATE 2:**

This is the [**sample project**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7xJ3vpXXdvQRE91Mmo2N09hbkE/view?usp=sharing) updated version based on cokeman19's answer. (the performance have been improved ~10 frames, But I need to perfect rendering)

**UPDATE 3 :**

Finally, I got an acceptable performance with the help of the cokeman19's answer and the contents of [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970683(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: If you really do plan on doing a lot of 3d animation you should use dx, animating directly with wpf can be a performance hog.

Comment: Can you post your XAML ?

Comment: I'm usually hate it, but at this time it's really hard to say something without real project or something close to it.
I'm think you have too much redraws somewhere or graphics linked to logic too tight so on any render it must do some work. 
 Also please check this article 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/karstenj/2006/10/16/wpf-3d-performance-troubleshooting/

Comment: @auburg , A sample project added Please see it.

Comment: @Arman Hayots , I don't have too much redraws . A sample project added Please see it.

Comment: On my machine FPS dropped to about 30 when Field Of View was set to more than 90. So it is rather machine specific issue. However, it is still interesting why Field Of View impacts performance so much in some cases.

Comment: 1. Sorry, but that's a dirty code. Never blindly copy patterns from books and tutorials. Patterns and practices just showing you ability, not a strong order to action.  My eyes are bleeding. 
2. I've done nothing, even not pressed `Start` button and got 16-13 FPS — so your counter have some troubles. Maybe it counting wrong. 

But anyways, that's code can be fast. Rewrite it to more simply and clean variant and it'll be faster.

Comment: Thank you for you'r reply ,Yes this is a dirty code, I've made it for sample. But in my main project I tried a various methods to get a good performance but still have not achieved a good performance. the FPS counter is not wrong and shows the `CompositionTarget.rendering` HZ correctly.

Comment: remove `SnapsToDevicePixels` and `ClipToBounds`. it improved frame rate from 7 fps to 30 fps in my computer. i dont know the reason so i dont put answer.

Comment: i just noticed two `ClipToBounds="True"`. you should only remove the one for TextBlock not Border.

Comment: @M.kazem thanks for you'r reply (and thanks for the ClipToBounds) , but I think you're wrong about : "...  from 7 fps to 30 fps ... "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's just a byproduct of the sample app, but under `Planerator.CreateVisualChild()`, it doesn't seem to be necessary to set the `GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial`.  For reference:

```
VisualBrush vb = new VisualBrush(_logicalChild);
SetCachingForObject(vb);  // big perf wins by caching!!
Material backMaterial = new DiffuseMaterial(vb);
...
GeometryModel3D backModel = new GeometryModel3D() { ..., BackMaterial = backMaterial };
```

The `BackMaterial` is a `VisualBrush` wrapper around the *logical* child, which doesn't belong to the visual tree, so rendering doesn't seem to make sense here.  Moreover, the logical child (the `LayoutInvalidationCatcher` class), is in turn a wrapper around the *visual* child, which is already rendered (using `_logicalChild`) in setting `frontModel.Visual`.

Removing the code for the creation and setting of `BackMaterial` brings the FPS up to ~55.

In addition, if it's an option, setting the following brings the FPS back up to 60, with no noticeable degradation in quality.

```
RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(_viewport3d, EdgeMode.Aliased);
```

Update:

The only other gain I was able to make was to set the `CacheMode` to `BitmapCache`, which may not be appliable for your needs.

```
frontModel.CacheMode = new BitmapCache(20) { EnableClearType = false };
```

Even on my slowest machine, this allowed for maximum FPS, but there are some drawbacks.  Because the zoom level is so high on the text element, and this technique creates a picture to use in the animation (instead of animating the UIElement itself), I had to set the scale level to 20 before it became *almost* visually imperceptible.  This of course has memory implications, as well.

Comment: You are right, thank you very much . It does not need to The BackMaterial. 

But with the changes that you said only ~10 frames have been better. (no up to 60)

I expect to animate a 2Dtext in 3D space to be able to achieve 60 frames.

 So I am waiting for a better response.

the sample source code was updated according to your recommendations.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include one additional possible option.

Comment: I did not think that the `BitmapCache` is so effective , And I mistakenly thought that it should be applied to the `TextBlock` . ( I got better results with increase the font size and reduce the scale level .)

Now I can accept your answer. Thank you .